# MaskedTextBox not showing anything if Text is bound to string that doesn't match mask

Tags: wpf, xtk

I am using a MaskedTextBox (from the Extended WPF Toolkit) to input/display an ID.  There are potentially old IDs in the database which do not match the mask, and what I would like it to do in this case is still display the string but have it give a validation error indicating that the ID does not match the mask.  Instead it is not displaying anything at all in the MaskedTextBox.  Is this functionality supported or do I need to somehow handle it manually?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One possible solution is mentioned in a comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922903/conversion-of-a-datetime-data-type-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-a-wpf-app

Comment: Well I need the ID to remain as-is until fixed manually by the user, so I'm starting to think that MaskedTextBox is not going to work for me in this case...